# beforeShowDate in DatePicker is always true when list is return

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

beforeShowDate in DatePicker is always true when I return a list. If a return a "true" or "false", it's working. I think it sees a list (which isn't null). What I do wrong ?
My aim is to custom some days in the calendar.

Code : https://jsfiddle.net/alex09/j9co36br/34/

JS

```
 $("#date").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    language: 'fr',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    beforeShowDay: jourDispo
  });

  function jourDispo(date) {
    console.log("I'm in jourDispo");

    // This is working
    // return false;
    // but not with array
    return [false, "red"];
  }
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label class="control-label requiredField" for="date">
        Date *
      </label>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control date_size" id="date" name="date" placeholder="JJ/MM/AAAA" type="text" required />
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.red a{
    background-color: #ffb3b3 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    color: White !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

It's maybe linked with resources so you can find all resources I used in the page (cf jsfiddle).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you are using [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html?highlight=beforeShowDay#beforeshowday) and referring [jQuery UI datepicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) documentation.

As per the [documentation of the plugin which you are using](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html?highlight=beforeShowDay#beforeshowday), the return value can be the following:

1. undefined to have no effect
2. A Boolean, indicating whether or not this date is selectable
3. A String representing additional CSS classes to apply to the date’s cell
4. An object with the following properties:

   - enabled: same as the Boolean value above
   - classes: same as the String value above
   - tooltip: a tooltip to apply to this date, via the title HTML
     attribute
   - content: the content to display in the day cell, rather than the default (day of month as text)

So update it with an object :

```
function jourDispo(date) {
  return { enabled : false, classes :  "red" };
}
```

Working demo : [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/eoazgr7q/)